# Google Maps Javascript API - isAdvancedMarkersAvailable : false

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

COULD NOT FIGURE IT OUT, USING MAPBOX API INSTEAD

I am trying to add advanced markers to my react project but I cannot make it work. I think the reason for this is the setting as shown in the picture. Does anybody know how I can change this setting to true?
[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soZnj.png)

Here is my code:

```
const mapOptions = {
    madId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAP_ID,
    center: { lat: 43.66, lng: -79.39 },
    zoom: 10,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  }

  function MyMap() {
    const [ map, setMap ] = useState();
    const ref = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      setMap(new google.maps.Map(ref.current, mapOptions))
    }, [])
    return (
      <>
        <div ref={ref} id="map"/>
        {map && <City map={map} />}
      </>
    )
  }

  const cityData = {
    A: {
      name: "Toronto",
      position: { lat: 43.66, lng: -79.39  }
    },
    B: {
      name: "Amsterdam",
      position: { lat: 53.66, lng: -79.39 }
    }
  }

  function City({map}) {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState(cityData);

    return (
      <>
        {Object.entries(data).map(([key, city]) => (
          <Marker key={key} map={map} position={city.position}>
            <div className="marker">
              <h2>{city.name}</h2>
            </div>
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </>
    )
  }

   function Marker({map, children, position}) {
    const markerRef = useRef();
    const rootRef = useRef();
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!rootRef.current) {
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        rootRef.current = createRoot(container);
        
        markerRef.current = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
          position,
          content: container,
        });
      }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      rootRef.current.render(children)
      markerRef.current.position = position;
      console.log(markerRef.current.map = map);
    }, [map, position, children])
  }
```

And my reference in the render:

```
<Wrapper apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY} version="beta" libraries={["marker"]}>
   <MyMap />
</Wrapper>
```

Inspired by this video made by Google: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kxYqoY2WwE

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapCapabilities

Comment: Thanks for your response @MrUpsidown, however I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. Where in my code would I load the advanced markers library?

Comment: You are apparently already loading it the way they suggest in the video with that line: `version="beta" libraries={["marker"]}`. Can you provide a codesandbox or alike where we can try it?

Comment: Hi @MrUpsidown, I have decided to use the mapbox api. It is a very useful tool and I found it to be easier to use than the google maps api. Thanks for your time anyway.